# Plone 4 : Display Clickable link in View Mode

Tags: hyperlink, plone

I am a new user working with plone4. I have a page in view mode that displays links e.g. http://www.somelink.com. I need to find a way of making the displayed field as a clickable URL. Which field type or widget will I have to use?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [text field](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/fields/fields-reference#text_field), the default widget should work fine for you.

~ or ~

if you have very specific needs, you could use a [string field](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/fields/fields-reference#string_field) and then [customize your widget](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/buildingblocks/skin/templates/customizing-at-templates/customizing-widgets).